# How to group objects by every date within a range of dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, group-by, ruby-on-rails-4

I can create a hash like this:

```
@time_offs_by_date = @time_offs.group_by{ |time_off| time_off.start_date}
```

Which I then iterate through using

```
@time_offs_by_date[date] # I am drawing a calendar date-by-date
# I then list details about every object grouped by the specified date
```

I would like to group my objects by every date included in the range between `time_off.start_date` and `time_off.end_date`.

**How would I do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
@time_offs_by_date = @time_offs.group_by{ |time_off| time_off.start_date..time_off.end_date }

@time_offs_by_date.each do |range, time_offs|
  # do your logic here
end
```

This will produce a Hash with Range objects as keys, and an array of TimeOff as values.

**Documentation** about the class Range (Ruby 1.9.3): http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html

Hope that helps!